# Importing GeoParquet file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, import, geoparquet

[GeoParquet](https://github.com/opengeospatial/geoparquet/) is a new geospatial vector data format that is built on Parquet. It looks super efficient in terms of storage and loading/saving data files. Is there a way to read a GeoParquet in QGIS?

Here is an example of a GeoParquet file: [example.parquet](https://github.com/opengeospatial/geoparquet/blob/main/examples/example.parquet).

Comment: You will need a QGIS version that is built to use a GDAL version that supports GeoParquet. The driver https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/parquet.html will be included in the GDAL 3.5.0 version that is right now waiting for the Project steering committee votes for acceptance. QGIS nightly development builds may have a GDAL-dev version with this driver already.

Comment: "Warning: This is not (yet) a stable specification that can be relied upon." source:https://github.com/opengeospatial/geoparquet

Comment: I have opened a feature request on QGIS for this: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/49454

Comment: On Windows (OSGeo4W), GDAL 3.5.1 is already available for QGIS 3.22.9 and 3.26.1, and GDAL 3.6.0 is already available for QGIS 3.27.0-Master nightly build.

Comment: recent QGIS version 3.28 comes with GDAL 3.6.0 and supports GeoParquet files

Answer (score 1):

As answered already in the comments: current QGIS versions can open GeoParquet files. This screenshot shows the linked file "example.parquet" in QGIS 3.35.

[image]